# Elasticsearch - Synonyms in a language analyzed field is producing terms that will not match

Tags: elasticsearch

Synonyms, keywords and language analyzers just don't work together.

I have the following settings:

```
POST index1
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "english_keywords": {
          "keywords": [
            ""
          ],
          "type": "keyword_marker"
        },
        "english_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "english"
        },
        "english_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": [
            "_english_"
          ]
        },
        "synonyms": {
          "ignore_case": "true",
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": ["Foo,Fruits=>Apples"],
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        },
        "english_possessive_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "possessive_english"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "english_synonyms": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "english_stop",
            "english_keywords",
            "english_stemmer",
            "english_possessive_stemmer",
            "synonyms"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "myType": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "english_synonyms"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST index1/myType
{
  "name": "Apples"
}
```

So, you already may know what the problem is, when analyzed `apples` turns to `appl`, which will cause a `match` query not working properly.

See the following results from the `_analyze` API.

```
GET index1/_analyze?field=name&text=fruits
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "fruit",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
GET index1/_analyze?field=name&text=apples
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "appl",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
GET index1/_analyze?field=name&text=foo
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "apples",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "SYNONYM",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea in how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is funny, but as I was writing the questions I came around with the solution.

The thing is, that Elasticsearch, apparently runs the filter on the text one by one, beginning with the first one, until the last one. So what I did was just change the order of the filter.

So this:

```
"analyzer":{  
  "english_synonyms":{  
    "filter":[  
      "lowercase",
      "asciifolding",
      "english_stop",
      "english_keywords",
      "english_stemmer",
      "english_possessive_stemmer",
      "synonyms"
    ],
    "type":"custom",
    "tokenizer":"keyword"
  }
}
```

Became this:

```
"analyzer":{  
  "english_synonyms":{  
    "filter":[  
      "lowercase",
      "asciifolding",
      "synonyms",
      "english_stop",
      "english_keywords",
      "english_stemmer",
      "english_possessive_stemmer"
    ],
    "type":"custom",
    "tokenizer":"keyword"
  }
}
```

I hope this help anyone who came to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent tool called [elyzer](https://github.com/o19s/elyzer/) that you can use to visualize how your tokens look like in each step of your analysis process. That usually helps spot the issues.

Here is the output when analyzing `fruits` with the original settings:

```
$ elyzer --es localhost:9200 --index test --analyzer english_synonyms --text fruits
TOKENIZER: keyword
{0:fruits}  
TOKEN_FILTER: lowercase
{0:fruits}  
TOKEN_FILTER: asciifolding
{0:fruits}  
TOKEN_FILTER: english_stop
{0:fruits}  
TOKEN_FILTER: english_keywords
{0:fruits}  
TOKEN_FILTER: english_stemmer
{0:fruit}   
TOKEN_FILTER: english_possessive_stemmer
{0:fruit}   
TOKEN_FILTER: synonyms
{0:fruit}
```

Here is the output when analyzing `fruits` after moving the `synonyms` token filter up in the list:

```
$ elyzer --es localhost:9200 --index test --analyzer english_synonyms --text fruits
TOKENIZER: keyword
{0:fruits}  
TOKEN_FILTER: lowercase
{0:fruits}  
TOKEN_FILTER: asciifolding
{0:fruits}  
TOKEN_FILTER: synonyms
{0:apples}  
TOKEN_FILTER: english_stop
{0:apples}  
TOKEN_FILTER: english_keywords
{0:apples}  
TOKEN_FILTER: english_stemmer
{0:appl}    
TOKEN_FILTER: english_possessive_stemmer
{0:appl}
```